Unexpected Control Characters in Docker Container Logs
I am using dockerode to capture logs from a running container. However, the log stream contains unexpected control characters. For example, I'm running C++ code to display "Believe," but I got this: "\u0001\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\bBelieve\n".
I’ve added a screenshot of the terminal output to provide more context.

Here is the implementation to create and execute code within a Docker container and capture the logs:
import Docker from "dockerode";

const docker = new Docker({ socketPath: "//./pipe/docker_engine" });

const startContainer = async (command) => {
  let codeOutput = "";
  let container;
  try {
    container = await docker.createContainer({
      Image: "image-name",
      Cmd: ["bash", "-c", command],
      Tty: false,
    });

    await container.start();
    const stream = await container.logs({
      stdout: true,
      stderr: true,
      follow: true,
    });

    stream.on("data", (data) => {
      codeOutput += data.toString();
    });
  } catch (error) {
    throw new Error(`Error occurred while starting container: ${error}`);
  }

  try {
    await container.wait();
    await container.remove();
  } catch (error) {
    throw new Error(`Error occurred while removing container: ${error}`);
  }
1
  return codeOutput;
};

export default { startContainer };

Is there any way to cleanly retrieve just the log content without these control characters?

Are you sure the logs are supposed to be in human-readable format?  That looks like a tagged format.  The \b before the string is 0x08, and the string is 8 letters long.

I'm not entirely sure about this. The logs are in a partially human-readable format, but I'd prefer them to be fully readable. I've updated the question with a screenshot of the terminal output to provide more clarity, as each line starts with specific characters.

I suspect these might be escape characters, so parsing them through xterm could be a good approach. What do you think?

No, they're not escape characters.  It's a binary format.  The first 7 bytes have a code number, maybe the level of the record.  That's followed by one byte with the length of the string, followed by the string.

Thanks for the clarification! That makes sense. If the first 7 bytes represent a code and the next byte indicates the string length, how would you suggest parsing or interpreting these logs into a fully readable format?

You just described the process.  Skip 7 bytes, read the length byte, read that many bytes and print them.  Repeat.
